# WCF - KeyInfo SecurityTokenReference

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, interop, x509

i must consume a Webservice where the Soap Request must have a signed BinarySecurityToken and the KeyInfo must be in following Format

```
<ds:KeyInfo>
                <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                    <wsse:Reference
                            ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"
                            URI="#pfxb65d8fe8-185a-4edc-6589-3a08270deca3"/>
                </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
```

Here is my customBinding

```
 AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement sec = 
            (AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement)SecurityBindingElement.CreateMutualCertificateBindingElement(MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10);



        sec.InitiatorTokenParameters = new X509SecurityTokenParameters { InclusionMode = SecurityTokenInclusionMode.Never };
        sec.RecipientTokenParameters = new X509SecurityTokenParameters { InclusionMode = SecurityTokenInclusionMode.Never };
        sec.ProtectTokens = false;
        sec.MessageProtectionOrder = System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageProtectionOrder.SignBeforeEncrypt;
        sec.SecurityHeaderLayout = SecurityHeaderLayout.Lax;
        sec.EnableUnsecuredResponse = true;
        sec.IncludeTimestamp = false;
        sec.SetKeyDerivation(false);
        sec.DefaultAlgorithmSuite = System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Basic256Sha256;
        //sign BST
        sec.EndpointSupportingTokenParameters.Signed.Add(new X509SecurityTokenParameters());


        cb.Elements.Add(sec);

        //Message
        cb.Elements.Add(new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap11, Encoding.UTF8));

        HttpsTransportBindingElement trans = new HttpsTransportBindingElement();            
        trans.RequireClientCertificate = true;

        cb.Elements.Add(trans);

        return cb;
```

This binding gets me nearly the requested format of the soap message.
Only the KeyInfo is different from the requested format.
It gives me

```
< KeyInfo>
 <o:SecurityTokenReference>
   <o:KeyIdentifier 
     ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-
     wss-x509-token-profile#X509SubjectKeyIdentifier"
     EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-
     wss-soap-message-security-
     1.0#Base64Binary">STRIPPED
   </o:KeyIdentifier>
  </o:SecurityTokenReference>
</KeyInfo>
```

and this is unfortunately not accepted by the server.

The Question is. How can i sign the BST and have the required KeyInfo?

Maybe someone of the WCF Gurus can help me out here?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Using SecurityTokenInclusionMode.Once creates the correct KeyInfo reference, but creates a copy of the BinarySecurityToken, which is also not accepted by the server.... 
Did you ever find a solution to this problem?